# pyside show.ui > showGui.py error: No module named pkg-resources (Windows 7 64 bit)

Tags: qt, pyside

I am trying to convert an .ui-file into a .py-file and it does not find the module named above in the title.
Information about my setup (perhaps here is the problem?):

C:\Entwicklung\Python33     <== Python v.3.3.0, 64 bit

C:\Entwicklung\Python33... <== with pyside v.1.1.2, 64 bit (IDLE from Python33 can find pyside correct)

C:\Entwicklung\Qt\Qt5.0.2   <== Qt 5.0.2-mingw47_32-x86-offline, 32 bit

(I used 32 bit for Qt because i hoped, there was the Qt-Designer included... but no.. where is the designer, by the way?)

With the commandline cmd i navigated into the folder 
C:\Entwicklung\Python33\Scripts where the pyside-uic.exe is placed, and also put my show.ui-file into this folder. then i've ran 
"pyside-uic.exe show.ui -o showGui.py" and the error shown in the title occured!

What did I do wrong?

Comment: what method you have used to install PySide ? if you are using easy_install  I recomment to update distrbute to latest version and reinstall the PySide. the latest version of distutils have fixes regarding to pyside scripts. btw, PySide does not support Qt 5.0, but that not matter because pyside distributions contains all qt libs and also designer and linguist tools.

Comment: I just downloaded the file from http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide_Binaries_Windows, the same version (3.3.) according to my version of Idle and installed it, just that

Comment: You need to install the distribute package. Download and run distribute_setup.py: http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py.

Comment: Ok now i ran your *.py-file and it downloaded a rar-Folder. what to do then?

Comment: what RAR folder ? After downloading distribute_setup.py and running command `python.exe distribute_setup.py` the scripts should download and install latest version of distribute from internet into python installed in your system. you should see following message on console at the end of the install process: 
`Finished processing dependencies for distribute==0.6.39
After install bootstrap.
Creating c:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c11-py3.3.egg-info
Creating c:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\setuptools.pth`

Comment: thanks a lot! thought it would work out of the box after a python/pyside install. but now it works perfectly!

Comment: also added as answer, so you can mark it as good solution :) and i have updated the documentation on PyPI https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide#installing-prerequisities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the distribute package.
Download and run distribute_setup.py [[python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py]](http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py):

```
python.exe distribute_setup.py
```